# Problem installing OTB-contrib on Ubuntu Xenial

Tags: ubuntu, orfeo-toolbox

I am trying to install OTB-contrib package in Ubuntu Xenial. I did the following:

- Download it and move it to /opt
- Run the script
- Added the following paths to my .bashrc file:

> ```
> export PATH="$PATH:/opt/OTB-contrib-6.0.0-Linux64/bin"
> export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/opt/OTB-contrib-6.0.0-Linux64/lib/python"
> export OTB_APPLICATION_PATH="/opt/OTB-contrib-6.0.0-Linux64/lib/otb/applications"
> ```

After that, I have tried to run the applications from the command line, but I get a error message. For example:

```
ignacio@ignacio-Athena:~$ otbcli_OrthoRectification
/opt/OTB-contrib-6.0.0-Linux64/bin/otbcli: 34: .: Can't open /opt/OTB-contrib-6.0.0-Linux64/bin/../otbenv.profile
```

Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: sounds very permissions based, what user is trying to acces the app, does that user have access.  Are you following any instructions, if not why move to opt?

Comment: I just checked and if I install it in my home directory it works like a charm. What do I need to do to make it available for all the users?

Comment: Agree that it is an issue related to files permissions. You need to check that users have read and execution access to OTB-contrib-6.0.0-Linux64 directory (and files inside it)